# Replaying a Core Animation animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I was wondering, what if I want to replay an animation I have already added to the layer? Do I need to add the animation to the layer each and every time I want it to play, or there's a way to replay an animation I have already added?

Thanks,
iLyrical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once animation gets finished then to repeat animation u will have to add new animation like this:

```
[yourView.layer removeAllAnimations];
[yourView.layer addAnimation:yourAnimation forKey:@"Key here"];
```

Comment: What happens (or could happen) if I dont remove all the animations?

Comment: by chance yourView.layer's layer is animating and u add your animation then your animation will take effect after completion of first or might be worse animation(mixing). So its better to remove all animation and add new animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the animation to repeat a certain number of times before it finishes using the `repeatCount` property but if you want to repeat an animation that has already finished you have to add it to the layer again.